# How to set the tomcat to act as a proxy server?

Tags: tomcat, proxy

Can i use Apache Tomcat to behave like a proxy server? I know there are other methods also, to create a proxy server [ using HTTP/Socks-5 , using google app engine, blah blah ]

The answer can be simply, *No* . or if it is possible to create a proxy server using Tomcat then please let us know.

Answer (score 1):

No, as far as I know tomcat cannot be configured to act as a proxy server. With programming of course everything is possible.

On the other hand nothing prevents you from deploying on it e.g. Apache MINA library and a couple of classes to configure it as a proxy server. Then you have a proxy server which can be deployed as part of your tomcat solution. But this has nothing to do with tomcat, other than that it happens to start the thing.

Comment: Well sometime a little programming is easier than configuring. But I was thinking about another use-case : delivering a single executable with all necessary functionality built in and preconfigured can make a  lot of sense if it must be maintained by "external" sysadmins. We use this to deliver internal aaplications to the Ops team as this cuts down in the training, documentation, incidents, speed of deployment, unreliability, etc...

Comment: Anyways, http://edwardstx.net/wiki/Wiki.jsp?page=HttpProxyServlet looks promising.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using a web app to do the http proxy. There are several ready-to-go web apps that you can use. [J2EP](http://sourceforge.net/projects/j2ep/) seems to work fine, and there are [others](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/ServletProxy)

Answer (score -2):

tomcat can not accomplish proxy funciton standlone, combine with apache or nginx, they can accomplish.

about details, you can see: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/proxy-howto.html